# Jupyter Notebook keeps crashing on VScode when opening a video window using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing a lane detection using openCV and i'm working on jupyter notebook on VScode.
when i run the code it runs fine and shows the window , but after the video ends the window freezes, when i try to force shut it , it crashes the kernel and i have to restart the kernel.
im working on a Conda kernel.

```
while video.isOpened():
   is_grabbed,frame = video.read()

if not is_grabbed:
    break


frame = get_detected_lanes(frame)

cv2.imshow('Lane',frame)


key = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff

if key == 27:
    break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

the code above is the driver code for the program and it works fine , there's just something with the videos whenever i open them on VScode.

i tried opening my webcam in another program and it works just fine and doesn't crash.

Comment: Indentation isn't correct. Move from if not is_grabbed: to if key == 27: inside while condition block.

Comment: you didn't actually **call** `destroyAllWindows`. a call requires the **parentheses**.